# Continuously differentiable function definition?

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, derivatives

I have a rather silly question. If I have a function

$$f: [a,b] \to \mathbb{C}$$

where $[a,b]\subset \mathbb{R}$, how is differentiability of $f$ defined?

Assuming this is supposed to be differentiability by the limit definition is it's conjugate also differentiable if $f$ is? I am having trouble coming up with counter examples.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In terms of the component functions and the complex norm.

If $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{C}$, $f = a(x)+ib(x)$, so $f$ is differentiable iff $a,b$ are as real-valued functions ($a: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$, likewise for $b$). Note that the introduction of $i$ on the second component does not fundamentally change differentiation as it was for a function $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}^2$

Comment: Thanks! The limit definition also makes this clear - I was being silly, being used to holomorphic functions, I made the mistake of assuming my variables were complex....

Answer (score 0):

Write $f(t)=u(t)+iv(t)$, then $f$ is differentiable if both $u$ and $v$ are. This is essentially the same definition as for vector-valued functions $f:[a,b]\to\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: Thanks! That makes sense. This was a dumb question - I realized that it is obvious via the limit definition that the conjugate is also differentiable. I was making a silly mistake.